# Cannot delete File on Fedora

Tags: files, permissions, rm, selinux

I have a file with following permission:

```
-rwSr-s---. 1 1634630331 1818884080 118784 Jun 29 1970 DailyUpdateClass.class
```

If I try to delete this file with root login, I get error.

```
rm: cannot remove ‘model/DailyUpdateClass.class’: Operation not permitted
```

I cannot change ownership nor I can do anythig else.

I posted it on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153567/cannot-delete-file-on-fedora?noredirect=1#comment39316532_25153567) and tried few things but no help so far.

I was recommended that I should try this on Unix Stack Exchange so requesting your assistance.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -A` in the directory containing the file?

Comment: In stack overflow you mention `gvfs`, how is the directory mounted. It may be that you don't have permission on the remote machine. If so having root access locally will not help.

Comment: What does `lsattr model/DailyUpdateClass.class` show? Where exactly is this file located? Please add the output of the `mount` command to your post.

Comment: @richrd ls -A only gives file name. Even though in Red. Using Fedora 20.

Comment: @garethTheRed Thanks. lsattr output is `-u-Diad--j------ DailyUpdateClass.class
`

I dont kow what it means.

Answer (score 5):

A number of possibilities:

- the trailing dot in the file permissions line `-rwSr-s---.` indicate extended permissions, either SE Linux (confirm with `ls -lZ`) or ACL style permissions (confirm with `getfacl` ) which may block root overrides.
- the file has been made immutable with `chattr` ; confirm the file system attributes with `lsattr`
- The file is on a NFS filesystem that is exported with the `root_squash`  option which re-maps the remote root user to an unprivileged account. Run the `rm` command as the actual file owner instead e.g. `sudo -u <file_owner> rm filename`
- the file is on read-only file-system, confirm with the `mount` command or `/proc/mounts`
- IIRC you can't remove the special device entries that represent kernel settings such as files on the `proc` and `sysfs` file systems, is that the case?

Comment: Strictly speaking, `sudo`’ing to a user who has write permission on the directory might be more useful than `sudo`’ing to the owner of the file.

Comment: Thanks @HBruijn. 

ls -lZ Gives following output `-rwSr-s---. tuser tgroup system_u:object_r:file_t:s0      DailyUpdateClass.class
`

lsattr gives following output `-u-Diad--j------ DailyUpdateClass.class`

I am unfamiliar with both of them.
It is not NFS. It is my laptop hard disk.
File System is not readonly. I can create folder and other files in same directory.

Comment: @garethTheRed's answer has explained your output and the resolution; `chattr -ia DailyUpdateClass.class` should remove the immutable flag and allow you to delete the file.

Answer (score 1):

Your file has the `immutable` extended attribute set, which is why you can't delete it.

`lsattr` returns the extended attributes on the file:

```
$ lsattr model/DailyUpdateClass.class
-u-Diad--j------ DailyUpdateClass.class
```

You will need to decipher all of the letters (`-u-Diad--j`)

The man page for `lsattr` will tell you to look at the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chattr.1.html) for `chattr` for a description of the extended attributes.  I've listed the relevant ones here:

> When a file with the `u` attribute set is deleted, its contents are
>   saved.  This allows the user to ask for its undeletion.  Note: please
>   make sure to read the bugs and limitations section at the end of this
>   document.
>
> When a directory with the `D` attribute set is modified, the changes
>   are written synchronously on the disk; this is equivalent to the
>   `dirsync` mount option applied to a subset of the files.

The `D` one is slightly worrying - it apparently is only used on directories, but you have a file.

> A file with the `i` attribute cannot be modified: it cannot be
>   deleted or renamed, no link can be created to this file and no data
>   can be written to the file.  Only the superuser or a process
>   possessing the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this
>   attribute.
>
> A file with the `a` attribute set can only be open in append mode for
>   writing.  Only the superuser or a process possessing the
>   `CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE` capability can set or clear this attribute.
>
> A file with the `d` attribute set is not candidate for backup when
>   the dump(8) program is run.
>
> A file with the `j` attribute has all of its data written to the ext3
>   or ext4 journal before being written to the file itself, if the
>   filesystem is mounted with the `data=ordered` or `data=writeback`
>   options.  When the filesystem is mounted with the `data=journal`
>   option all file data is already journalled and this attribute has no
>   effect.  Only the superuser or a process possessing the
>   `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE` capability can set or clear this attribute.

To fix these, use `chattr`.  For example, to remove the immutable and append attributes:

```
# chattr -ia model/DailyUpdateClass.class
```